# How do I go about finding the $log$ function that passes through 2 points?

Tags: logarithms

In my example I have a point $P$:

$P = (1,3)$

And another point $Q$

$Q = (8,8)$

I need to find a logarithmic function which passes through both $P$ and $Q$ and

$y = 8$ when $x > 8$.

I have no idea where to start. How can I go about finding such a function?

Comment: purely logarithmic or..?

Comment: @TheIntegrator yes

Comment: Impossible for a logarithmic function to pass trough $(1, 3)$

Comment: What is the form of the function you are looking for?  Is it $y=a \log x$, for example?  That has only one parameter, so is unlikely to pass through two points.  It also has the problem that $\log 1=0$

Comment: rather than a logarithmic function, you could try polynomials

Comment: @RossMillikan Rather than having a linear line between $P$ and $Q$, I want to have a function which looks concave-down and increasing between those two points, and the inverse of an exponential increase in $y$  between those 2 points.(EDIT: concave-down not up)

Comment: would it be fine if the function is of form $f(x)=ln(kx+c)$

Comment: You should have said that at the beginning.  You can follow the approach in my answer to evaluate $k$ and $c$

Comment: That will not stop increasing after $x=8,$ though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want a curve of the form $y=a\log x + b$ you can just plug your two points in to find $a$ and $b$.  We get 
$$3=a \log 1 +b\\8=a \log 8 +b\\3=b\\5=a\log 8\\a=\frac 5{\log 8}\\y=\frac 5{\log 8}\log x+3$$
The derivation does not care what base of logs you use.  If you use $2$ the final expression simplifies to $$y=\frac 53\log_2 x +3$$

Comment: Sorry my vagueness, my question was not specific enough.  I need an example of a function that's the inverse of an exponential function, which starts at $P$ and passes through $Q$. However when $x>8$ then $y = 8$. So a function that is inverse of exponential and then stops increasing after $Q$

Comment: To stop it increasing after $x=8$ you can just declare that $y=8$ for all $x \ge 8$.

Answer (score 0):

Seeing one of the points is $(1,3)$ then solve the equation $a\cdot ln(8) + 3 = 8$

$a = \frac{5}{ln(8)} = 2.4045$

Hence $y = 2.4045\cdot ln(x) + 3$